# How to pass state values from one component to another using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass the state value from one component to another component. My  requirement is to develop two components where component A handles the state for Student Details and component B wants to render the details of student from component B in the table format. Intially I have tried to import component B in component A and I passed the state of the component A. And I tried to use the map function in component B and tried to display the data in table format but I end up with undefined but I can see the array values in console. And I tried to do the map in component A itself and pass the values as props to component B. Now also I am getting the undefined. Any can help me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance. I have wrote down the codes.

**//Old Approach
Component A :**

```
  const studentDetails = [
    { studentID: "001", studentName: "StuOne", studentMarks: "80" },
    { studentID: "002", studentName: "StuTwo", studentMarks: "90" },
    { studentID: "003", studentName: "StuThree", studentMarks: "60" },
    { studentID: "004", studentName: "StuFour", studentMarks: "70" },
    { studentID: "005", studentName: "StuFive", studentMarks: "85" },
  ];

  const [studentdata, setStudentData] = useState([studentDetails]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Details stuDetails={studentdata} />
    </div>
  );

**Component B** 
function Details({ stuDetails }) {
  console.log("Studetals", stuDetails);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="Main">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Student Mark</th>
          </tr>
          {stuDetails.map((val) => {
            console.log("val", val);

            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{val.studentID}</td>
                <td>{val.studentName}</td>
                <td>{val.studentMarks}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**New Approach**

```
**Component A :**
function Main() {
  const studentDetails = [
    { studentID: "001", studentName: "StuOne", studentMarks: "80" },
    { studentID: "002", studentName: "StuTwo", studentMarks: "90" },
    { studentID: "003", studentName: "StuThree", studentMarks: "60" },
    { studentID: "004", studentName: "StuFour", studentMarks: "70" },
    { studentID: "005", studentName: "StuFive", studentMarks: "85" },
  ];

  const [studentdata, setStudentData] = useState([studentDetails]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {studentdata.map((value) => (
        <Details
          id={value.studentID}
          name={value.studentName}
          mark={value.studentMarks}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

**Component B** 

function Details(props) {
  console.log("PROPS", props);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="Main">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Student Mark</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>{props.id}</tr>
          <tr>{props.name}</tr>
          <tr>{props.mark}</tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `const [studentdata, setStudentData] = useState([studentDetails]);` studentDetails is already an array, just change it to `useState(studentDetails);`

Comment: @Fauzanadhim, Thanks much! just to clarify, if I add an extra array in the useState then the data will be in the following format [[name:value]] that is the reason I ma getting undefined am I right ?

Comment: yes correct, since it will become an array of array `[[{ studentID: "001", studentName: "StuOne", studentMarks: "80" }]]`,